# Uploading local json files in mongodb with python

Tags: python, json, mongodb

I have installed mongoDB on AWS and interested in uploading files from my local computer on mongoDB.I have opened mongoDB on AWS using my terminal and created a SSH tunnel to create a connection to mongoDB running on AWS.

I am using the following code to upload local json files on mongoDB

```
data_path="/Users/username/Desktop/file.json"

with open(data_path) as f:
    file_data = json.load(f)

db.collectionname.insert(file_data) client.close()
```

I am getting the following error

```
<ipython-input-23-0317fba0bf38> in <module>()
      2 
      3 with open(data_path) as f:
----> 4     file_data = json.load(f)
      5 
      6 reviews.insert(file_data)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in load(fp, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    297         cls=cls, object_hook=object_hook,
    298         parse_float=parse_float, parse_int=parse_int,
--> 299         parse_constant=parse_constant, object_pairs_hook=object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    300 
    301 

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/__init__.py in loads(s, encoding, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    352             parse_int is None and parse_float is None and
    353             parse_constant is None and object_pairs_hook is None and not kw):
--> 354         return _default_decoder.decode(s)
    355     if cls is None:
    356         cls = JSONDecoder

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/json/decoder.py in decode(self, s, _w)
    340         end = _w(s, end).end()
    341         if end != len(s):
--> 342             raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
    343         return obj
    344 

JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 394)
```

Can someone guide me?
Thanks

Comment: Seems to be a problem with the source JSON not parsing. That's what the error is telling you, so perhaps you should look at the contents of the file. Most likely it's something like objects `{}` that are presented on newlines, so you probably need to read the file "one line at a time" and then parse the bytes from JSON "per line" instead of the whole file.

Comment: Thanks.It worked when I read the file line by line